# Flex Facebook Application return HTTP Verb error

Tags: apache-flex, facebook

I've followed the Adobe tutorial on how to make a Facebook App with Flex.

If I access the page from the server, everything works.
http://server01.televic.systray.be/stages/facebookintegration/flextryout/

But when I access it trough the facebook app url,
http://apps.facebook.com/flextryout

I get the following error:

> ```
> The page cannot be displayed
>
> The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid
> ```
>
> method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt
>   access.
>       Please try the following:
>
> ```
> Contact the Web site administrator if you believe that this request
> ```
>
> should be allowed.
>       Make sure that the Web site address displayed in the address bar
>   of your browser is spelled and
>   formatted correctly.
>       HTTP Error 405 - The HTTP verb used to access this page is not
>   allowed.
>       Internet Information Services (IIS)
>
> ```
> Technical Information (for support personnel)
>
> Go to Microsoft Product Support Services and perform a title search
> ```
>
> for the words HTTP and 405.
>       Open IIS Help, which is accessible in IIS Manager (inetmgr), and search
>   for topics titled Setting Application
>   Mappings, Securing Your Site with Web
>   Site Permissions, and About Custom
>   Error Messages.

Does anyone have an idea what my problem could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem myself.

The POST method for html was not allowed on the server.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I don't have any forms, just simple hello message to test it out. what to do?